SQL query for JSON Parsing - find key based on value
Given a column in table which is a JSON format like
Input: table name my_table with a column called my_col of JSON format
{
  "key1": [
    "val1"
  ],
  "key2": [
    "val2"
  ],
  "key3": [
    "val3"
  ]
}

Output: I want to retrieve all key values where value matches certain criteria in SQL query. so in this looking for where value = val3 which should return key3
Tried JSON SQL UDFs which retrieve values based on keys but not the other way around.

But you don't want where the value EQUALS "val3".  You want a key where the array CONTAINS "val3".  That's complicated.  What are you using?

What RDBMS are you using? (Tag it)

since you have json each key contains an array of one value it would be little bit more complex
declare @my_table table (id int identity(1,1), my_col  nvarchar(max))

insert into @my_table values
('{"key1":["val11"],"key2":["val12"],"key3":["val13"]}')
,('{"key1":["val21"],"key2":["val22"],"key3":["val23"]}')

select  
    v.value
from @my_table 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(my_col) root
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (root.value) v
where id = 1 and root.[Key] = 'key3'



result would be val13
running example
